# Managing lots of Apps

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, ant

So I am working on a project where we have lots of Apps which are basically the same (Same code) but also different in terms of icons etc.

I am working with Eclipse with the Mercurial Plugin (Which I really like) which creates a local source control folder.

Now I wanted to ask which is the best way to manage all of those projects. For example I create a new feature in the Main Project and I want all of the other projects to be updated and compiled (and uploaded to the play store -> I don't think that one is possible though) with the new code automatically.

I have heard of Maven and ANT but I don't know exactly what those tools can do for me or if I'm even on the right track?

Or would I have to develop something like this myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what Library Projects are for. You create one base project and convert it to a library project (Eclipse: Project Properties / Android / is Library [x])
The other projects, which are depending on the base project have to include it as a library project (Eclipse: Project Properties / Android)

If you want to change res files like drawables you have to name the files the same and the android builder will overwrite the library project icon with the one from your project.
Thats it.

Comment: Wow ok that sounds easy enough. Thank you for that!